# Protocol buffers for spanner APIs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I want to connect to google spanner from a c++ program. Is there a client library exists for c++? Where can I get gRPC protocol buffers for spanner APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spanner protobuf definitions can be found at https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/spanner. At the time of writing, there are only [four Google client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reference/libraries) for Spanner: Go, Java, Node.js, and Python.